# Widgets do not appear in the emulator widget list

Tags: android, android-emulator, widget, android-widget

I have 2 widgets in my application. I want to test them on different versions of android. On my physical device and other physical devices, the widgets appear correctly in the widget list, but when I run the application on the emulator in android studio, they do not appear. What could be the problem? If this is the problem of android studio emulator, so maybe there is some emulator, where i can change the android version and it works with widgets?

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of widget list]

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.PetrSUShedule"
        tools:targetApi="33">

        <service
            android:name=".Widgets.FullScheduleService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_REMOTEVIEWS" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".Widgets.FullScheduleProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="Полное расписание"
            android:widgetCategory="home_screen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
                <action android:name="com.example.petrsushedule.Widgets.ACTION_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/full_schedule_widget_info" />
        </receiver>

        <receiver
            android:name=".Widgets.NextLectureWidget"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="Следующая пара"
            android:widgetCategory="home_screen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/next_lesson_widget_info" />
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.LecturerScheduleActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.LecturersActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.GroupScheduleActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activities.GroupActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```